# Simple Logistic Regression Error in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scikit-learn

Here is the line of code. I know the issue is that I only have a 1-d array but I cannot figure the code for casting it to a 2-d array inline.

```
def classification_model(model, data, predictors, outcome):
    model.fit(data[predictors],data[outcome])
```

where data is a 1-d array that has been read from a .csv file.

The `classification_model()` is invoked like this:
`classification_model(LogisticRegression(), data, 'HvA', 'FTR')` 
Where FTR and HvA are column names in the .csv and therefore array positions in my data array (Pandas)

Trace is:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "Predict.py", line 112, in <module>
    classification_model(LogisticRegression(), reader, 'HvA', 'FTR')
  File "Predict.py", line 15, in classification_model
    model.fit(data[predictors],data[outcome])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1174, in fit
    order="C")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 531, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 370]
```

The heading line and first line of data from .csv file

```
FTHG    FTAG    FTR HTHG    HTAG    HTR HS  AS  HST AST HF  AF  HC  AC  HY  AY  HR  AR  VCH VCD VCA Bb1X2   BbMxH   BbAvH   BbMxD   BbAvD   BbMxA   BbAvA   BbOU    BbMx>2.5    BbAv>2.5    BbMx<2.5    BbAv<2.5    BbAH    BbAHh   BbMxAHH BbAvAHH BbMxAHA BbAvAHA PSCH    PSCD    PSCA    HvA

0   0   1   0   0   1   25  10  5   2   19  11  7   2   3   3   0   1   3.4 3.5 2.25    39  3.5 3.26    3.6 3.42    2.3 2.2 37  1.95    1.86    2.02    1.92    24  0.25    2.02    1.95    1.94    1.9 3.22    3.5 2.36    0
```

Thanks

Comment: Does `data[col_name].values.reshape(len(data), 1)` work?

Comment: Great! that did work although the problem didn't really stop there I now get an error in the lines below that is due to the same issue:

Comment: kf = KFold(data.shape[0], n_folds=5)
   error = []
   for train, test in kf:
    # Filter training data
    train_predictors = (data[predictors].iloc[train,:])

Comment: gives : Trace: Traceback (most recent call last): File "Predict.py", line 31, in classification_model
    train_predictors = (data[predictors].iloc[train,idx])
     return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1449, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 126, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: I think .iloc in pandas only takes one indexer. It should just be .iloc[train], not .iloc[train,:]

Comment: I took that code from a walk through which is why I didn't question it.... Hero!!!  Thank you

Comment: Haha, glad to help. If you haven't already checked it out, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html is a great walk through and resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data[col_name].values.reshape(len(data), 1)
```

As given by Michael K above